# Creating enums with lombok

Tags: java, enums, lombok

I am using project lombok with my application. I was creating an enum. If I use

> @AllArgsConstructor

annotation with my enum, it doesn't recognise the constructor, enum throws and error that it cannot take string argument.

How to resolve this?

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor

@AllArgsConstructor
public enum Direction {
    NORTH("NORTH"), // all these enums give error, for no constructor
    SOUTH("SOUTH"),
    EAST("EAST"),
    WEST("WEST");

    @Getter private String value;
}
```

P.S.: I am using intellij-idea, which has lombok plugin install. My lombok dependency version is: 1.16.20

Comment: I works just fine for me with Lombok 1.16.20. There may be a problem with the lombok install in IntelliJ. Try to do something else with Lombok in a non-enum, if that doesn't work either, it's certain to be an installation issue

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt It works fine for non-enum classes for me

Comment: Can you show the code that doesn't work (rather than the code that does work as you've posted now) ? Then we can see what might be wrong.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt done

Comment: FWIW, the field should probably be static, and if you're just repeating the instance's name, there's no reason to have it. (Presumably this is simplified.)

Comment: @chrylis can you elaborate that as answer here?

Comment: The only problem with the code that you posted is the missing semicolon in your second import statement. Change `import lombok.AllArgsConstructor` to `import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;`. After that, your code works just file, both from the maven command line (in a maven project) and in Eclipse.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt you were right, it was an issue with my IDE, and strangely it got fixed after restarting the IDE. It seems the plugin lombok was not in the effect. Thank you

Comment: For me I found I was using a semicolon instead of a comma on the 2nd last enum value.

Comment: @PriyankThakkar, What's the error?

Comment: Faced with same issue, restarting doesn't help. And on CI pipeline getting compilation issue, so looks like its not related to IDE. Decompiled enum class showed it has private constructor, but it have @AllArgsConstructor.

Answer (score 10):

You also have to have enabled "Enable annotation processing" in Settings -> Build -> Compiler -> Annotation Processor

Answer (score 6):

That’s usually an issue with your IDE, and strangely, it gets fixed after restarting the IDE. It’s when the plugin lombok is not in the effect yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could also move Getter annotation above the enum clarification and AllArgsConstructor annotation, and also set 'value' as final:

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum Direction {
    NORTH("NORTH"),
    SOUTH("SOUTH"),
    EAST("EAST"),
    WEST("WEST");

    private final String value;
}
```

Anyway, thank you for your question. It helped me to solve my problem.