# @AllArgsConstructor not generating constructor on Enum

Tags: java, enums, lombok

I'm trying to define an Enum for the States that I have for another class.

This is my code

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;

@AllArgsConstructor
public enum State {
    PUBLISHED("published"),
    UNPUBLISHED("unpublished");

    private String value;

    public String value() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

But I keep getting this error:

> [ERROR] .../State.java:[12,14] constructor State in enum State cannot
>   be applied to given types;
>   [ERROR]   required: no arguments
>   [ERROR]  found: java.lang.String
>   [ERROR]   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Is there any problem with @AllArgsConstructor?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49837774/creating-enums-with-lombok) could help.

Comment: the only weird thing in your code is that you gave your getter the same name as your variable, instead of a valid getXX(). But allArgsConstructor should work just fine

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Wouldn't this be better?

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
public enum State {
    PUBLISHED("published"),
    UNPUBLISHED("unpublished");
    private final String value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Enable annotation processing should fix this issue. 
(Preferences-->Build, Execution, Deployment)-->Compiler-->Annotation processors