# Duplicate code across enums .. is there an approach to centralize common code in these enums?

Tags: java, inheritance, enums

I have the following 3 enum's in my project, which are all very similar.

Since each enum has at least 2 common fields i.e `key` and `code`, is there any way that I can make the common:

- constructors
- getters
- field declarations

shared to all of my enums? Without having to declare inside each one.

I know `no extends clause allowed for enum`.

But is there an elegant way to achieve reuse of the common parts of these enums?

```
public enum CarType {

  SEAT("2000", "001"),
  FIAT("3000", "002");

  String key;

  String code;

  CarType(String key, String code) {
    this.key = key;
    this.code = code;
  }

  public String getKey() {
    return key;
  }
  public String getCode() {
    return code;
  }
}

public enum TruckType {

  MERCEDES("4000", "001"),
  FORD("5000", "002");

  String key;

  String code;

  TruckType(String key, String code) {
    this.key = key;
    this.code = code;
  }

  public String getKey() {
    return key;
  }
  public String getCode() {
    return code;
  }
}

public enum VanType {

  JEEP("6000", "001", "40"),
  KIA("7000", "002", "50");

  String key;

  String code;

  String tankSize;

  VanType(String key, String code, String tankSize) {
    this.key = key;
    this.code = code;
    this.tankSize = tankSize;
  }

  public String getKey() {
    return key;
  }
  public String getCode() {
    return code;
  }
  public String getTankSize() {
    return tankSize;
  }
}
```

Comment: No. Code-generators may help. I wouldn't consider using them for such a case, but probably this is what you're looking for. Also you can consider refactoring your code in favor of "simple" classes (loosing the `==`/`!=` operators check for ref/value-equality, `switch` statement support, in-annotations use and whatever else enums can be used for). I'd stay with using enums just like you have now.

Comment: Additionally, I would not really consider it code duplication. It more looks like "structurally/semantically the same/look-alike" to me. Here is a very similar code-gen use case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49837774/creating-enums-with-lombok

Comment: Another remark since you understand why enums and inheritance don't play well together. Code generators are a least of two kinds: 1) javac extensions like Lombok I put a link to above; 2) source code generators. The former can be used on fly if it's a part of `javac` (and your IDE supports it, Lombok has both) generating common boilerplate code on fly. Not sure if it's easy to implement a custom Lombok extension in case of necessity. The latter simply generates plain text .java files before `javac` acts so that the generated code might contain the "duplicated" code as generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Enum** - is a special kind of **class** that is very restricted. And you may think of **enum constants** as if they are **public static final** fields (*note: explicit modifiers are not allowed with enum constants*).

That actually resembles the **Singleton pattern**.

All enum constants are **eagerly** initialized when an enum is being loaded into memory. And that is the simplest implementation of the **singleton** when an instance (*in this case instances*) is being initialed before any of its static methods of fields can be accessed.

My idea is to introduce an **abstract** class `VehicleType` that will contain two string fields `key` and `code`, *constructor* and *getters*.

And every **enum** will turn into a **concrete class** that extends the `VehicleType` class. Apart from *constructors* and *static final fields* in these classes, we'll need to declare only a single *field* inside the `VanType` and provide a *getter* for it.

The code for that will look like that.

```
public abstract class VehicleType {
    protected String key;
    protected String code;

    public VehicleType(String key, String code) {
        this.key = key;
        this.code = code;
    }

    // getters + common behaviour
}
```

```
public class CarType extends VehicleType {
    public static final CarType SEAT = new CarType("2000", "001");
    public static final CarType FIAT = new CarType("3000", "002");

    private CarType(String key, String code) {
        super(key, code);
    }
}
```

```
public class TruckType extends VehicleType {
    public static final TruckType SEAT = new TruckType("4000", "001");
    public static final TruckType FIAT = new TruckType("5000", "002");

    private TruckType(String key, String code) {
        super(key, code);
    }
}
```

```
public class VanType extends VehicleType {
    public static final VanType JEEP = new VanType("6000", "001", "40");
    public static final VanType KIA = new VanType("7000", "002", "50");

    private String tankSize;

    private VanType(String key, String code, String tankSize) {
        super(key, code);
        this.tankSize = tankSize;
    }

    public String getTankSize() {
        return tankSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer actually brings nothing new to the OP as the OP has clearly stated the inheritance tag in the question. Enums has some language support, e.g. switch, annotation values. None of the above can have support in the latter. Moreoever, it even brings more code that the OP seems trying to avoid.

Comment: @T-E-R-R-O-R-U-S-S-I-A I'm aware of what enum is meant for and how it differs from a regular class. Inheritance and enums together is an impossible combination. OP has to choose either, design problems are almost always about compromises. Since none of us knows for sure how OP is intended to use these enums, let them say their word.